# Java Swing Repaint an image

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I'd like to implement a DragAndDrop for an Image but can't seem to get the Swing repaint function to work on the specific Image.

Code:

```
public class playerFrame extends JFrame{
...
    private void destroyerImageMouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)  
    }                                             
    repaintCurrentPosition(evt);
    }               

    public void repaintCurrentPosition(MouseEvent e){
        this.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        this.repaint();
    }
```

this.repaint <- this function repaints the whole frame and not just the Image I'd like it to repaint, which is about 50x50 size.
How do you repaint a specific JPEG image without creating a new class?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`this.repaint` will force the parent frame to be repainted. Call `repaint` only on the control holding your image.

Example: to refresh this image loaded onto the JLabel:

```
ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif");
label = new JLabel("Image and Text", icon, JLabel.CENTER);
```

You do:

```
label.repaint();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
not just the Image I'd like it to repaint, which is about 50x50 size
```

[JComponent#paintImmediately](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) carefully with EDT

Answer (score 1):

How are you doing the drag and drop?

The easiest way is to just add an Icon to a JLabel and then drag the label around. Everytime you invoke setLocation(...) on the label it will repaint() itself.

The [Component Mover](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) class does all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Call `repaint` only on the panel where your image is drawn.